# JQuery - Fade Out Elements After Being Created

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a JQuery game (Just to get around with using JQuery) and on certain collisions, an "explosion" class is created.

Right now I'm using `$("#game").append("the div html code goes here")` to add it in the game div. Now, how do I make it so after the element is created, it fades out after being created? I tried doing something along the lines of `$(".explosion").load(function goes here)` but that doesn't seem to work :\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("the div html code goes here").appendTo("#game").fadeOut();
```

If you want to get rid of it after it fades out, you can do this:

```
$("the div html code goes here").appendTo("#game").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**Working demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qbJgh/

Answer (score 0):

This is simplified version of the answer above mine

```
$('#itemSelector').fadeOut(600, function(){
    $('#itemSelector').remove();
});
```

This code can be wrapped in click function.