# Fade in/out doesn't work with an append div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tried the best I could and did some research, I still couldn't figure it out.
My goal is to create an easy coded lightbox for a part of my final examination website that im working on.

Please need help with this annoying problem of mine, would be very appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 
 $('button').click(function() {
  
  $('body').append(' <div id="lb-shadow"><p id="lb-x">[ x ]</p></div> ');
  $('body').append(' <div id="lb-container"></div> ');
  $('#lb-shadow').fadeIn(6000 );
  $('#lb-container').fadeIn(6000);
  
  $('#lb-shadow').click(function(){
   $('#lb-container').fadeOut(6000);
   $('#lb-shadow').fadeOut(6000);
   
   $('#lb-container').detach();
   $('#lb-shadow').detach();
  });
 });
 
 
 
 
});
```

```css
#lb-btn{
 position:absolute;
 outline:0;
 border:0;
 padding:5px 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
 background-color:black;
}
#lb-btn p{
    padding:5px;
 color:#ccc;
 border:1px solid white;
}


#lb-shadow{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
#lb-x{
 color:#ccc;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 float:right;
 margin:15px;
 cursor:pointer;
 transition: ease .3s;
}
#lb-x:hover{
 color:white;
}
#lb-container{
 position:absolute;
 height:400px;
 width:600px;
 left:calc(50% - 300px);
 top:calc(50% - 200px);
 background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
    <title>Min hemsida</title>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cindex.css">
    
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/cindex.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<button id="lb-btn"><p> Login / Register </p></button>







</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery - Fade Out Elements After Being Created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935646/jquery-fade-out-elements-after-being-created)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the click handler, try attaching the event listener globally like so, this way should work even if the element is created after the listener. (Otherwise the duplicate comment on your question should solve the issue)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '#lb-shadow', function(){
        $('#lb-container').fadeOut(6000);
        $('#lb-shadow').fadeOut(6000);
        $('#lb-container').detach();
        $('#lb-shadow').detach();
    });

    $('button').click(function() {
        $('body').append('<div id="lb-shadow"><p id="lb-x">[ x ]</p></div>');
        $('body').append('<div id="lb-container"></div>');
        $('#lb-shadow').fadeIn(6000);
        $('#lb-container').fadeIn(6000);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but it wouldn't work for me but atleast you gave me some energy to work with it a bit more this night instead of tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

I just added display:block on the lb-container and lb-shadow. Apperently the fade effects trigger it automatically and I did cut down my js code aswell.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 
 $('button').click(function() {
  
  $('body').append(' <div id="lb-shadow"><p id="lb-x">[ x ]</p></div> ');
  $('body').append(' <div id="lb-container"></div> ');
  $('#lb-shadow').fadeIn();
  $('#lb-container').fadeIn();
  
  $('#lb-shadow').click(function(){
   $('#lb-container').fadeOut();
   $('#lb-shadow').fadeOut();
  });
 });  
});
```